# Error starting profiler in Visual Studio 2015 CTP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use the Profiler in Visual Studio 2015 CTP found under the "Analyze" menu but I get the following error message:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.CounterInfo,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The profiler works fine in Visual Studio 2013. I am trying to profile some C++ code.

Based on some advice in another question I tried running as Administrator but it didn't help.

I can't find the dll in the Visual Studio 2015 install directory. In Visual Studio 2013 it is found in the `Team Tools\Performance Tools` directory but there doesn't seem to be a `Team Tools` directory in my Visual Studio 2015 install directory.

Do I need to install something else to get the performance tools?